# What can you do if the higher-order derivative test is inconclusive?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

The second-derivative test states that if $x$ is a real number such that $f'(x)=0$, then:

1. If $f''(x)>0$, then $f$ has a local minimum at $x$.
2. If $f''(x)<0$, then $f$ has a local maximum at $x$.
3. If $f''(x)=0$, then the text is inconclusive.

But there's no need to despair if the second-derivative test is inconclusive, because there is the higher-order derivative test.  It states that if $x$ is a real number such that $f'(x)=0$, and $n$ is the smallest natural number such that $f^{(n)}(x)\neq 0$, then:

1. If $n$ is even and $f^{(n)}>0$, then $f$ has a local minimum at $x$.
2. If $n$ is even and $f^{(n)}<0$, then $f$ has a local manimum at $x$.
3. If $n$ is odd, then $f$ has an inflection point at $x$.

But the higher-order derivative test can also be inconclusive, if $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ for all $n$.  My question, what can you do if the higher-order derivative test is inconclusive?

Is the first-derivative test the only option at that point, or are there other options?

EDIT: I’m interested in finding a method that depends only on the [germ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics)) of $f$.

EDIT 2: Let me explain more precisely what I’m saying regarding the germ.  Let $X$ be the set of all functions $f$ infinitely differentiable at $a$ where $f^{(n)}(a)=0$ for all $n$.  Two functions $f$ and $g$ in $X$ belong to the same [germ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics)) if there is an open interval $I$ containing $a$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$ in $I$.  Now let $Y$ be the set of germs of $X$.  I want to know if there exists a nontrivial function $F:Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that if $F$ evaluated at a particular germ yields a positive number, then all the functions in the germ have a local minimum at $a$, and if it yields a negative number then all the functions in the germ have a local maximum at $a$.

Comment: The case you are talking about is for the polynomials of degree $m<n$. However, if you see that $f^n$$(x)$ $=$ $0$ $\forall n\in N$, then then the function must be a constant one, right ?? @Keshav Srinivasan

Comment: @AnikBhowmick I'm not talking about polynomials, I'm talking about smooth functions in general.  If you have an infinitely differentiable function $f$ whose derivatives of all orders evaluated at a given point $x$ is zero, then the higher-order derivative test fails.  But that doesn't mean that $f$ is a constant function.  For instance consider the example function given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function

Comment: I assume you meant to ask what can you do if the higher-order derivative test is inconclusive?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes